# cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsarray, accessorytype

In my to-do list app I'm using static cells to display an NSMutableArray of to-do items that never change. Once a person taps the cell an accessoryType of .Checkmark and is marked as completed. What I'm trying to do and haven't found an answer to yet is once every item in the array is completed and adds a checkmark a completionDate is returned for the entire list. The closest method I've found that can be called on NSArray or NSMutableArray is -removeAllObjects, but I don't want the Array destroyed. This is a daily checklist that needs to continue to be available. I would really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction or even a better suggestion for how to do this. Thanks!

```
var checklistItems: NSMutableArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadInitialData()

 func loadInitialData(){

    var item1 = Checklist(name: "Check Tires")
    self.checklistItems.addObject(item1)

    var item2 = Checklist(name: "Check Controls")
    self.checklistItems.addObject(item2)

    var item3 = Checklist(name: "Check Lights")
    self.checklistItems.addObject(item3)

    var item4 = Checklist(name: "Check Oil")
    self.checklistItems.addObject(item4)

    var item5 = Checklist(name: "Check Chassis")
    self.checklistItems.addObject(item5)

    var item6 = Checklist(name: "Check Sidestand")
    self.checklistItems.addObject(item6)

 }

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.checklistItems.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListPrototypeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    var checklistItems: Checklist = self.checklistItems.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as Checklist

    cell.textLabel?.text = checklistItems.itemName
    if checklistItems.completed{

        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark



    }

    else{

        cell.accessoryType = .None

    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)

        var tappedItem: Checklist = self.checklistItems.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as

        Checklist

        tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed

        tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: what you need is to know when all items are completed?

Comment: Yes. Once the entire list has been completed by the user it returns month/day/year that the list was completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you want to return a completion date from this list, perhaps via a delegate method or through an unwind segue, but I can suggest a method for determining whether the entire list is checked.

If you add an `NSMutableSet` to hold the checked items you can quickly determine that all items are checked when the count of the checked item set is equal to the count of the array -

```
var checklistItems: NSMutableArray = []
var checkedItems = NSMutableSet()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)

        var tappedItem: Checklist = self.checklistItems.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as

        Checklist

        tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed

        if (tappedItem.completed) {
           checkedItems.addObject(tappedItem)
        } else {
           checkedItems.removeObject(tappedItem)
        }
        if (self.allChecked()) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindFromChecklist", sender:self)
        } else {
            tableview.reloadData()
        }
}

func allChecked() -> Bool {
    return checkedItems.count == checklistItems.count
}
```

I have added an unwind segue call - You can simply grab the current date and time in your unwind method in the calling view controller or you could set the current date in a property of this view controller before invoking the unwind segue

Comment: Thanks Paulw11, if once completed it could unwind to the main view controller with the date of completion.

Comment: You need to think about the user experience you want - do you want the unwind to occur as soon as the last item is checked?  Do you want the user to press a "back" or "done" button that is only enabled if everything is checked? Do you want to prompt the user once the last item is checked?

Comment: I want the unwind to occur as soon as the last item is checked. No reason to hit done. I'll be keeping a cancel button though in case they don't have time to complete it or if they are just checking the list out.

Comment: Also, now that i've added the NSMutable set i'm getting a warning that the class doesn't have an initializer. I'm looking around to figure out why this is.

Comment: You probably need to add an initialisation of the set in your init() function, although the default value specified by `NSMutableSet()` should be enough

Comment: For some reason NSMutableSet() causes the class TableViewController to require an init method. When I comment it out the error goes away. There's nothing in apple docs about it.

Comment: Paul I am so sorry man. I figured it out. I had var checkedItems: NSMutableSet() instead of var checkedItems = NSMutableSet(). I can't believe I did that. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: No worries. I was wondering because I couldn't reproduce the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Paul's method to check if 
You don't really need to create another array. A 'swifty' way.

```
    func allChecked() -> Bool
    {
// create an array with only the uncompleted items 
       let uncompletedArray = self.checkListItems.filter { $0.completed == false}
 // if this array is empty all items are completed
       return uncompletedArray.count == 0;
    }
```

Comment: I did think of this approach but involves repeatedly iterating the array although admittedly it is a small array. FWIW you can do the same thing in Objective-C with a block.  There isn't anything particularly "Swifty" about this approach